# Apache Redirect (using .htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm sort of a novice at using mod_rewrite in .htaccess, please forgive me. I've searched far and wide for an answer but perhaps I'm not looking in the right places, or perhaps .htaccess isn't even the right place to do this kind of thing.

Let's say I own two domains: **joebloggs.com** and **bloggs.com**.

When you put **`joebloggs.com`** into your browser I'd like it to redirect to **`https://www.bloggs.com/joe`**.

However, if you go to **`joebloggs.com/foobar`**, I'd like to redirect to **`https://www.bloggs.com/foo/bar`**.

*note: I know this seems counterproductive, going from a shorter URL to a longer one, but the problem is that marketing materials were already disseminated with the URL **`joebloggs.com/foobar`**... :-/*

The way I've tried to structure this in the .htaccess file hasn't worked thus far.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#
# redirect joebloggs.com/foobar to https://www.bloggs.com/foo/bar
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^joebloggs\.com\/foobar [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.joebloggs\.com\/foobar [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https\:\/\/www\.bloggs\.com\/foo\/bar [L,R=301,NC]
#
# redirect joebloggs.com to https://www.bloggs.com/joe
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^joebloggs\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.joebloggs\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https\:\/\/www\.bloggs.com\/joe [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

When I put **`joebloggs.com`** into a browser, it redirects correctly to **`https://www.bloggs.com/joe`** - but when I try to go to **`joebloggs.com/foobar`**, the URL remains intact and thus goes to a 404 page (because it doesn't exist).

What am I doing wrong? Am I not doing this the optimal way, or not using .htaccess/mod_rewrite as it was intended?

Sorry for being long-winded, I hope I gave enough information. Thanks for any help and time spent on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first set of rules is entirely useless. Update the second set to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?joebloggs\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.bloggs.com/foo [R=301,L,NC,QSA]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?joebloggs\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^foo(.*)$ https://www.bloggs.com/foo/$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this and see how it works! 

In the meantime, what about the first set of rules makes it useless? Is it just that it's redundant when replaced with the set that you provided?

Comment: @theRBF The variable `HTTP_HOST` does not receive the URL path.

Comment: Okay, thanks @hjpotter92, that explanation makes sense. I tried your suggestion and it didn't work for me, but... I just edited my problematic code a little bit above because I realized that the way I was presenting it was a little confusing and maybe misled you a bit (sorry about that).


In summary, I'd like to redirect `joebloggs.com/foobar` to `https://www.bloggs.com/foo/bar`, but also `joebloggs.com` to `https://www.bloggs.com/joe`.

Comment: @theRBF Updated above.

Comment: thanks again @hjpotter92 - but, I'm afraid the second rule doesn't seem to go where I need it to go, it still 404s on me with the URL unchanged.

Comment: @theRBF It'd help if you actually show what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tested this elsewhere on a test environment setup and it worked, so thanks for the help! There must be some other overriding or inherited rule somewhere that's messing me up. I'll have to check with the original designers. Thanks again.